# failing to install dlib on windows 10

Tags: python, pycharm, dlib

Trying to install dlib on Windows 10 using pycharm package manager.
I have Numpy, opencv-python, setuptools and wheel installed.
tried installing dlib then got the first error asking me to install CMake.

Now I'm getting this:
(tried installing visual studio but it had no effect).

```
    Collecting dlib   Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d5/5c/aa64510aa354d562ecba7edecd500b020280741140e5d91ff5ec1c6f8289/dlib-19.13.1.tar.gz Building wheels for collected packages: dlib   Running setup.py bdist_wheel for dlib: started   Running setup.py bdist_wheel for dlib: finished with status 'error'   Complete output from command C:\Users\Tom\venv\Scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Tom\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\dlib\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-f_njkl2_ --python-tag cp36:  running bdist_wheel   running build   running build_py   package init file 'dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)   warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.
     running build_ext   Building extension for Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 16:07:46) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\dlib\tools\python
-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\dlib\build\lib.win32-3.6
-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\Users\Tom\venv\Scripts\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\dlib\build\lib.win32-3.6'
-- Building for: NMake Makefiles   -- The C compiler identification is unknown   -- The CXX compiler identification is unknown   CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
    The CMAKE_C_COMPILER:

      cl

    is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

    To use the NMake generator with Visual C++, cmake must be run from a shell
    that can use the compiler cl from the command line.  This environment is
    unable to invoke the cl compiler.  To fix this problem, run cmake from the
    Visual Studio Command Prompt (vcvarsall.bat).

    Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
    variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
    the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.

     CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
    The CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:

      cl

    is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

    To use the NMake generator with Visual C++, cmake must be run from a shell
    that can use the compiler cl from the command line.  This environment is
    unable to invoke the cl compiler.  To fix this problem, run cmake from the
    Visual Studio Command Prompt (vcvarsall.bat).

    Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
    variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path
    to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.

     -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!   See also "C:/Users/Tom/AppData/Local/Temp/pycharm-packaging/dlib/build/temp.win32-3.6/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log". See also "C:/Users/Tom/AppData/Local/Temp/pycharm-packaging/dlib/build/temp.win32-3.6/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log". Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\dlib\setup.py", line 256, in <module>
      'Topic :: Software Development',
    File "C:\Users\Tom\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-39.1.0-py3.6.egg\setuptools\__init__.py", line 129, in setup
    File "C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\Tom\venv\lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 202, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\dlib\setup.py", line 133, in run
      self.build_extension(ext)
    File "C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\dlib\setup.py", line 169, in build_extension
      subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
    File "C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 291, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)   subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\Tom\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\dlib\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\Tom\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\dlib\\build\\lib.win32-3.6', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\\Users\\Tom\\venv\\Scripts\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\Tom\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\dlib\\build\\lib.win32-3.6']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
     ----------------------------------------   Running setup.py clean for dlib Failed to build dlib Installing collected packages: dlib   Running setup.py install for dlib: started
    Running setup.py install for dlib: finished with status 'error'
    Complete output from command C:\Users\Tom\venv\Scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Tom\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\dlib\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install
--record C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-1kold5c8\install-record.txt
--single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers C:\Users\Tom\venv\include\site\python3.6\dlib:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    package init file 'dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
    warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

    running build_ext
    Building extension for Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 16:07:46) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]
    Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\dlib\tools\python
-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\dlib\build\lib.win32-3.6
-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\Users\Tom\venv\Scripts\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\dlib\build\lib.win32-3.6'
    -- Building for: NMake Makefiles
    -- The C compiler identification is unknown
    -- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
    CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
      The CMAKE_C_COMPILER:

        cl

      is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

      To use the NMake generator with Visual C++, cmake must be run from a shell
      that can use the compiler cl from the command line.  This environment is
      unable to invoke the cl compiler.  To fix this problem, run cmake from the
      Visual Studio Command Prompt (vcvarsall.bat).

      Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
      variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
      the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


    CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
      The CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:

        cl

      is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

      To use the NMake generator with Visual C++, cmake must be run from a shell
      that can use the compiler cl from the command line.  This environment is
      unable to invoke the cl compiler.  To fix this problem, run cmake from the
      Visual Studio Command Prompt (vcvarsall.bat).

      Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
      variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path
      to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    See also "C:/Users/Tom/AppData/Local/Temp/pycharm-packaging/dlib/build/temp.win32-3.6/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
    See also "C:/Users/Tom/AppData/Local/Temp/pycharm-packaging/dlib/build/temp.win32-3.6/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\dlib\setup.py", line 256, in <module>
        'Topic :: Software Development',
      File "C:\Users\Tom\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-39.1.0-py3.6.egg\setuptools\__init__.py", line 129, in setup
      File "C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\Tom\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-39.1.0-py3.6.egg\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
      File "C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 545, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\dlib\setup.py", line 133, in run
        self.build_extension(ext)
      File "C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\dlib\setup.py", line 169, in build_extension
        subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
      File "C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 291, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\Tom\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\dlib\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\Tom\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\dlib\\build\\lib.win32-3.6', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\\Users\\Tom\\venv\\Scripts\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\Tom\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\dlib\\build\\lib.win32-3.6']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

    ----------------------------------------

  Failed building wheel for dlib Command "C:\Users\Tom\venv\Scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Tom\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\dlib\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install
--record C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-1kold5c8\install-record.txt
--single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers C:\Users\Tom\venv\include\site\python3.6\dlib" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\dlib\
```

What am I missing here?
I'm really baffled.

Comment: try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58777497/how-to-solve-issue-related-to-installation-of-dlib-on-windows-10/58857306#58857306

Answer (score 14):

```
pip install https://pypi.python.org/packages/da/06/bd3e241c4eb0a662914b3b4875fc52dd176a9db0d4a2c915ac2ad8800e9e/dlib-19.7.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl#md5=b7330a5b2d46420343fbed5df69e6a3f
```

Try this cmd command, it worked for me

Comment: Thank you so much.  That's the first thing I've gotten to work, and I've followed learnopencv's instructions and tried a bunch of dlib versions (installed dependencies like cmake, etc).

Comment: make sure your python version is 3.6 . it is not working with 3.7

Comment: this one is 19.7.0 for  dlib (19.19.0) raw repository link?

Answer (score 5):

I have followed below steps to install face_recognition (dlib):-

1. Re-installed Python 3.6.6 (https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.6/python-3.6.6-amd64.exe).
2. pip3 install cmake
3. pip3 install dlib
4. pip3 install face_recognition

It worked for me.

Comment: You can install cmake with pip?  That's so much easier.  (Unfortunately it's still not enough, you still need to install Visual Studio 2015 or later, so I'm still stuck, but at least one step is taken care of. :-\)

Answer (score 3):

**If you have conda installed in your system then follow these steps:**

- conda create -n py36 python=3.6
- activate py36
- conda config --add channels conda-forge
- conda install numpy
- conda install scipy
- conda install dlib

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is for windows, But by chance if someone is looking for solution for this on Mac,

Try this command, worked for me

```
pip install https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/05/57/e8a8caa3c89a27f80bc78da39c423e2553f482a3705adc619176a3a24b36/dlib-19.17.0.tar.gz#SHA256=92587c81b0165e933593f505fdf099dface0d0f8ec874b1d8655fc774598911f
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have installed Visual Studio, you need to make sure that you have selected **Clang tools**

Also use command Prompt (cmd) and be patient when **pip install dlib** it will take more than 5 min to be compiled

[image: Clang tools]

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the below steps:

1. install Python version you like
2. install cmake from https://cmake.org/download/ and add it to the path when install it
3. install visual studio from https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools, then go to modify -> individual components -> choose the following:
   (MSBuild/MSVC v142 - VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 build tools (v14.27)/C++ 2019 Redistributable Update/C++ CMake tools for Windows/C++/CLI support for v142 build tools (14.27)/C++ Clang-cl for v142 build tools (x64/x86)/C++ Clang Compiler for Windows (10.0.0)/Windows Universal CRT SDK/MSVC v140 - VS 2015 C++ build tools (v14.00)/Windows 10 SDK (10.0.19041.0)/C++ 2019 Redistributable MSMs))
4. open the visual studio and create new project as cmake c++
5. you will be prompt to update the windows 10 sdk after building the project
6. install updates for SDK
7. go to windows terminal
8. pip install dlib

this works perfectly for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you the answer. The CMAKE_C_COMPILER:

```
    cl

  is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

  To use the NMake generator with Visual C++, cmake must be run from a shell
  that can use the compiler cl from the command line.  This environment is
  unable to invoke the cl compiler.  To fix this problem, run cmake from the
  Visual Studio Command Prompt (vcvarsall.bat)."
```

Try to compile using the Visual Studio command prompt. The path to it there should be correct too.

Answer (score 0):

The best method to install dlib and openCV is given [here](https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv-3-and-dlib-on-windows-python-only/).

It simply uses pip to perform all the installations.
The major things that people miss or do a mistake in for Windows are declaring the PATH variables and saving them to valid address in your pc apart from the proper version matching. The above blog clearly signifies the versions to be used and declarations of PATH variables.

Just a 3 step process:-

1. Install `anaconda`
2. Activate Virtual Environment
3. Install `openCV` and `dlib` using `pip` (or any other required packages)

Comment: Please provide the main points of the provided link to your answer.

Comment: Why does installing without a venv throw an error?

Answer (score 0):

Linux error solution

```
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential cmake
$ sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-dev
$ sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
$ pip3 install dilb
```

Comment: This isn't an answer to this question because the issue is being faced on Windows and the solution provided isn't for windows. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer for the guidelines.

Comment: He asked for Windows 10. Linux is a different OS.

Answer (score -3):

Use the following code in the terminal which is accessible through Alt+F12 on your keyboard.

```
pip install dlib==19.8.1
```

You should be good to go.