# Dlib installation error?

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio, cmake, dlib

Visual studio 2015 is not installed
I have installed all the requirements before building dlib in python:
Cmake

python 3.6 and other bindings.

while installing dlib using pip:

```
pip install dlib
```

Got an error:

```
Collecting dlib
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/df/aa/6a9bb2a763107bb2606d6ee1aa65fcd3b51375a9ef6436e9c9280b0dd63c/dlib-19.15.0.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: dlib
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for dlib ... error
  Complete output from command "c:\users\vikas tiwari\anaconda3\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\VIKAST~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4f4b8868\\dlib\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\VIKAST~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-nnayeybw --python-tag cp36:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  package init file 'dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
  running build_ext
  Building extension for Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 29 2018, 13:32:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
  Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\VIKAST~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4f4b8868\dlib\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\VIKAST~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4f4b8868\dlib\build\lib.win-amd64-3.6 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\users\vikas tiwari\anaconda3\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\VIKAST~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4f4b8868\dlib\build\lib.win-amd64-3.6 -A x64'
  -- Building for: Visual Studio 14 2015
  -- Selecting Windows SDK version  to target Windows 10.0.17134.
  CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
    Failed to run MSBuild command:

      C:/Program Files (x86)/MSBuild/14.0/bin/MSBuild.exe

    to get the value of VCTargetsPath:

      Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 14.0.25420.1
      Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

      Build started 8/7/2018 1:07:47 PM.
      Project "C:\Users\Vikas Tiwari\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4f4b8868\dlib\build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\CMakeFiles\3.12.0\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).
      C:\Users\Vikas Tiwari\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4f4b8868\dlib\build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\CMakeFiles\3.12.0\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj(14,2): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
      Done Building Project "C:\Users\Vikas Tiwari\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4f4b8868\dlib\build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\CMakeFiles\3.12.0\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.

      Build FAILED.

      "C:\Users\Vikas Tiwari\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4f4b8868\dlib\build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\CMakeFiles\3.12.0\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
        C:\Users\Vikas Tiwari\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4f4b8868\dlib\build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\CMakeFiles\3.12.0\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj(14,2): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

          0 Warning(s)
          1 Error(s)

      Time Elapsed 00:00:00.03


    Exit code: 1



  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "C:/Users/Vikas Tiwari/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-4f4b8868/dlib/build/temp.win-amd64-3.6/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\VIKAST~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4f4b8868\dlib\setup.py", line 257, in <module>
      'Topic :: Software Development',
    File "c:\users\vikas tiwari\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 129, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "c:\users\vikas tiwari\anaconda3\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "c:\users\vikas tiwari\anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "c:\users\vikas tiwari\anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "c:\users\vikas tiwari\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 202, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "c:\users\vikas tiwari\anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "c:\users\vikas tiwari\anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "c:\users\vikas tiwari\anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "c:\users\vikas tiwari\anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "c:\users\vikas tiwari\anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\VIKAST~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4f4b8868\dlib\setup.py", line 133, in run
      self.build_extension(ext)
    File "C:\Users\VIKAST~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4f4b8868\dlib\setup.py", line 170, in build_extension
      subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
    File "c:\users\vikas tiwari\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 291, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\VIKAST~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4f4b8868\\dlib\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\VIKAST~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4f4b8868\\dlib\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.6', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\\users\\vikas tiwari\\anaconda3\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\VIKAST~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4f4b8868\\dlib\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.6', '-A', 'x64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for dlib
  Running setup.py clean for dlib
Failed to build dlib
Installing collected packages: dlib
  Running setup.py install for dlib ... error
    Complete output from command "c:\users\vikas tiwari\anaconda3\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\VIKAST~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4f4b8868\\dlib\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\VIKAST~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-aol24hcc\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    package init file 'dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
    running build_ext
    Building extension for Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 29 2018, 13:32:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
    Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\VIKAST~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4f4b8868\dlib\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\VIKAST~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4f4b8868\dlib\build\lib.win-amd64-3.6 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\users\vikas tiwari\anaconda3\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\VIKAST~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4f4b8868\dlib\build\lib.win-amd64-3.6 -A x64'
    -- Building for: Visual Studio 14 2015
    -- Selecting Windows SDK version  to target Windows 10.0.17134.
    CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
      Failed to run MSBuild command:

        C:/Program Files (x86)/MSBuild/14.0/bin/MSBuild.exe

      to get the value of VCTargetsPath:

        Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 14.0.25420.1
        Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

        Build started 8/7/2018 1:07:50 PM.
        Project "C:\Users\Vikas Tiwari\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4f4b8868\dlib\build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\CMakeFiles\3.12.0\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).
        C:\Users\Vikas Tiwari\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4f4b8868\dlib\build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\CMakeFiles\3.12.0\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj(14,2): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
        Done Building Project "C:\Users\Vikas Tiwari\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4f4b8868\dlib\build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\CMakeFiles\3.12.0\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.

        Build FAILED.

        "C:\Users\Vikas Tiwari\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4f4b8868\dlib\build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\CMakeFiles\3.12.0\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
          C:\Users\Vikas Tiwari\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4f4b8868\dlib\build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\CMakeFiles\3.12.0\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj(14,2): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

            0 Warning(s)
            1 Error(s)

        Time Elapsed 00:00:00.03


      Exit code: 1



    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    See also "C:/Users/Vikas Tiwari/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-4f4b8868/dlib/build/temp.win-amd64-3.6/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\VIKAST~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4f4b8868\dlib\setup.py", line 257, in <module>
        'Topic :: Software Development',
      File "c:\users\vikas tiwari\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 129, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "c:\users\vikas tiwari\anaconda3\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "c:\users\vikas tiwari\anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "c:\users\vikas tiwari\anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\vikas tiwari\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "c:\users\vikas tiwari\anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 545, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "c:\users\vikas tiwari\anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\vikas tiwari\anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\vikas tiwari\anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "c:\users\vikas tiwari\anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\vikas tiwari\anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\VIKAST~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4f4b8868\dlib\setup.py", line 133, in run
        self.build_extension(ext)
      File "C:\Users\VIKAST~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4f4b8868\dlib\setup.py", line 170, in build_extension
        subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
      File "c:\users\vikas tiwari\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 291, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\VIKAST~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4f4b8868\\dlib\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\VIKAST~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4f4b8868\\dlib\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.6', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\\users\\vikas tiwari\\anaconda3\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\VIKAST~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4f4b8868\\dlib\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.6', '-A', 'x64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

    ----------------------------------------
Command ""c:\users\vikas tiwari\anaconda3\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\VIKAST~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4f4b8868\\dlib\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\VIKAST~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-aol24hcc\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\VIKAST~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4f4b8868\dlib\
```

I really don't have any idea what's the real issue here. Do i have to install Visual Studio to compile c++ files of dlib ?
Don't have VS 2015 installed right now!!

Answer (score 20):

Here is how I solved the same issue.

1. Make sure you have installed cmake and *CMAKE_FOLDER\bin* added it in environment varaible
2. Install anaconda
3. then run following commands in anaconda shell.

`conda update conda`

`conda update anaconda`

4. create new environment `conda create -n env_dlib python=3.6`
5. activate enviroment `conda activate env_dlib`
6. install dlib `conda install -c conda-forge dlib`

Verify your installation in python shell using

`import dlib
 dlib.__version__`

Answer (score 5):

Forget Everything and try the method to install dlib and/or opencv [here](https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv-3-and-dlib-on-windows-python-only/) from scratch.

It's a very simple 3 step method

1. Install `anaconda`
2. Activate virtual enviroment using cmd
3. Install `dlib` and `opencv` using pip through cmd.

You can connect to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50970555/failing-to-install-dlib-on-windows-10/53720808#53720808) thread as well.

Answer (score 4):

Here you go :

- Download CMake from [cmake](https://cmake.org/download/) and add it to PATH(C:\Program Files\CMake\bin)
- Install dlib using `pip`(pip install dlib==19.4)