# How to solve issue related to installation of dlib on Windows 10?

Tags: python, python-3.7, face-recognition, dlib

I am trying to install dlib for face-recognition for python 3.7 on windows 10, I explored few ways but I am getting errors.I tried below steps-

1. Installed cmake using 'pip install cmake'. This worked.
2. Downloaed the Dlib source(.tar.gz) from the Python Package Index : https://pypi.org/project/dlib/#files extract it and enter into the folder.
3. Ran the installation: python setup.py install

I am getting below error.

*

```
*C:\Program Files\dlib-19.18.0>python setup.py install
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing dlib.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to dlib.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to dlib.egg-info\top_level.txt
package init file 'dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
reading manifest file 'dlib.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
no previously-included directories found matching 'tools\python\build*'
no previously-included directories found matching 'dlib\test'
writing manifest file 'dlib.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build\bdist.win-amd64\egg
running install_lib
running build_py
running build_ext
Building extension for Python 3.7.3 (default, Apr 24 2019, 15:29:51) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]
Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Program Files\dlib-19.18.0\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Program Files\dlib-19.18.0\build\lib.win-amd64-3.7 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\Users\Sriparna\Anaconda3\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Program Files\dlib-19.18.0\build\lib.win-amd64-3.7 -A x64'
-- Building for: NMake Makefiles
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
  Generator
    NMake Makefiles
  does not support platform specification, but platform
    x64
  was specified.
CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Program Files/dlib-19.18.0/build/temp.win-amd64-3.7/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 261, in <module>
    'Topic :: Software Development',
  File "C:\Users\Sriparna\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "C:\Users\Sriparna\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Users\Sriparna\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Users\Sriparna\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\Sriparna\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 67, in run
    self.do_egg_install()
  File "C:\Users\Sriparna\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 109, in do_egg_install
    self.run_command('bdist_egg')
  File "C:\Users\Sriparna\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\Sriparna\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\Sriparna\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\bdist_egg.py", line 172, in run
    cmd = self.call_command('install_lib', warn_dir=0)
  File "C:\Users\Sriparna\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\bdist_egg.py", line 158, in call_command
    self.run_command(cmdname)
  File "C:\Users\Sriparna\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\Sriparna\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\Sriparna\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install_lib.py", line 11, in run
    self.build()
  File "C:\Users\Sriparna\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\install_lib.py", line 107, in build
    self.run_command('build_ext')
  File "C:\Users\Sriparna\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\Sriparna\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "setup.py", line 135, in run
    self.build_extension(ext)
  File "setup.py", line 172, in build_extension
    subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
  File "C:\Users\Sriparna\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 347, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Program Files\\dlib-19.18.0\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Program Files\\dlib-19.18.0\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.7', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\\Users\\Sriparna\\Anaconda3\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Program Files\\dlib-19.18.0\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.7', '-A', 'x64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.*
```

*

Can you please advise how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

In my system i'd done using Anaconda. The Dlib library supports python 3.6 to 3.7.0 in conda environments.

follow the instruction to install face recognition model,

1. install Anaconda from https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/#download-section
2. in conda prompt, create an environment using this command

   **conda create --name env_name python=3.7.0**
3. then activate the env

   **conda activate env_name**
4. install dlib

**conda install -c conda-forge dlib=19.17**

5. now install face_recogintion models using pip

**pip install face_recogntion**

Comment: Hi, thanks. I did installation of Visual studio and then ran dlib installation from VS command prompt.It worked.

Answer (score 0):

**Installing face_recognition on Windows 10**

Requirements:

> 1. Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 (or newer) with C/C++ Compiler installed.
> 2. Microsoft Visual C++ (MSVC) 14.0 installed (need to install the visual c++ build tools)
> 3. CMake for windows and add it to your system environment variables
> 4. Boost installed and added to system environment variables
> 5. Python 3 with the same system type as your OS (ie. 64-bit, 32-bit)

**Installing MSVC 14.0 and Cmake for windows**

> 1. Download Microsoft C++ build tools from https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/ and
>    install
> 2. Once the installation finished, click on modify in the Visual Studio Build Tools 2019 (2) section
> 3. Go to the Individual components tab, under the Compilers, build tools, and runtimes, tick on C++ CMake tools for Windows and MSVC v140
>
> - VS 2015 C++ build tools (v14.00) and click modify. The Visual Studio Installer will begin to download and install MSVC 14.0 and Cmake for
>   you

**Adding MSVC 14.0 and Cmake to System Variables**

> 1. On the search tab, type This PC and right-click, choose properties
> 2. Go to the Advanced system settings, under Advanced tab click on Environment Variables
> 3. Under System variables,  click New… and fill the following:    Name: VS140COMNTOOLS    Value: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>    14.0\Common7\Tools\
> 4. Click OK
> 5. Under User variables, click on variable named Path and click Edit…
> 6. Click New and fill “C:\Program Files\CMake\bin”
> 7. Click OK, click OK again

**Installing Boost and face_recognition**

> 1. Download Boost library source code or binary release for your current MSVC from https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/
> 2. Extract the Boost source files into C:\local\boost_1_XX_X (X means the current version of Boost you have). You may need to create local
>    directory
> 3. Open Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio and go to the current directory of Boost extracted and try these commands to compile
>    Boost:    bootstrap    b2 -a --with-python address-model=64
>    toolset=msvc runtime-link=static
> 4. If you successfully compile Boost, it should create compiled files in stage directory
> 5. Go to Command prompt and type $ pip install face_recognition